# Graph API Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know had many same question on this website but still cannot find out the reason.I have a Facebook account then I goto developer Facebook page to create an app then I create an iOS app which had integrated Facebook API(login, get friends list). Then when I login to get taggable-friends with the above Facebook account, everything is ok. The problem is when I try to login by another Facebook account then I get error when get taggable-friends list.Here is my code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          NSDictionary *result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                          for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) {
                              NSDictionary *picData = [friend objectForKey:@"picture"];
                              NSDictionary *picDetail = [picData objectForKey:@"data"];

                              [friendsList addObject:[friend name]];
                              [avatarLink addObject:[picDetail objectForKey:@"url"]];
                              NSLog(@"name: %@,Link: %@", [friend name], [picDetail objectForKey:@"url"]);
                          }
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              [tblView reloadData];
                          });

                      }];
```

I also try to fix by code: `[FBSession setActiveSession:self.session];` but did not work. The error as below:

```
  Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x7f9bea9172a0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x7f9be86297f0, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x7f9be863d450, appID: 811449395585015, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x7f9be8554390>, expirationDate: 2015-01-23 09:55:49 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-11-25 08:53:50 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "public_profile",
    "basic_info",
    email,
    "contact_email",
    "user_friends"
)>, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 10;
            message = "(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
    headers =     (
                {
            name = Expires;
            value = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
        },
                {
            name = "Cache-Control";
            value = "no-store";
        },
                {
            name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
            value = "*";
        },
                {
            name = Pragma;
            value = "no-cache";
        },
                {
            name = "Content-Type";
            value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
        },
                {
            name = "Facebook-API-Version";
            value = "v2.2";
        },
                {
            name = "WWW-Authenticate";
            value = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review\"";
        }
    );
}}
```

sorry for long log, but I want to be sure you got all the info so can help me to found the reason. Any help will appreciate.

**Edit**

I can use another Facebook account to get the above friends list, but before that I need to **add specific account as a tester** on Facebook Developer page so that I can use those account for login then get friends list.Now I had a question that it'll not useful when I public my app, cause I cannot add hundred users as a tester on my config app, and event I don't know the Facebook account of person will use my app. So, **will I need to submit my app for review by Facebook**, then another user can login and get friends list when they use my app(without config for those users as a tester in my app on Facebook Developer page)? or have another way to fix this problem?please help me to make this clearly.Many thanks!

Comment: You don't think: "(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review ". Can have something to do with it?

Comment: Yes,I had read it before but don't know where(which field) to config this.And not sure this is the problem, so I decide to post this question.Please help me in detail.

Comment: Taggable are not useful if you are not using publish_actions so I assume you are using that? If so submit it. If you are not what are you trying to do?

Comment: I also tried with `public_actions` but get the error when login `Invalid Scope: public_actions`

Comment: detail of error here: `com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginOtherError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode=100, NSLocalizedFailureReason=com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginOtherError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x7fc6c0c45cb0, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID`

Comment: I had read: `publish_actions will now include basic publish_stream permissions ` So I replace `publish_stream ` by just only `publish_actions`. So now I can login success but still get the same error when try to get taggable-friends list

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with my app. I submitted it to Facebook couple of times. But it seems that this authorization can only be used in order to tag friends in stories. If you are trying to retrieve the full friend list of a user for any other reasons than that, Facebook will not approve your app and you will only be able to access the friends with the account you set to test the app.
Hope it helps...

Comment: The problem is not just cannot get friends list by taggable by another account. I also get the error when try to share(post) to the facebook wall by another account

Comment: the error when share by another Facebook account: `Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x7fc64b15efc0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x7fc648da5a10, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler:`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this information helps:

> To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins,
>   developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be
>   reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review
>   please read our documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: can you please elaborate?